# Getting all items from dictionary values which are also list of items

Tags: c#, .net, list, lambda, expression

let's say I have the following dictionary :

```
public Dictionary<Room, List<Booking>> rooms = new Dictionary<Room, List<Booking>>();
```

I need to get all available bookings regardless of the room, using lambda expression.

for example I need to do the same as the following code

```
List<Booking> allBookings = new List<Booking>();
        foreach (List<Booking> listOfBooking in rooms.Values)
            foreach (Booking bookingItem in listOfBooking)
                allBookings.Add(bookingItem);
```

any Ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var allBookings = rooms.Values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Alternatively, view it as flattening by the `Value` property of each pair in the dictionary:

```
var allBookings = rooms.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Gotta love LINQ :)

Comment: That ...... is ........ awesome !!!!! yes , that is what I mean, so the question should be like: how to flatten all values in dictionary ??

Comment: @NourSabouny: Well it's really how to flatten all the values in a dictionary, where each value is itself a collection. But your question was nice and clear, particularly as you'd given the imperative code which did what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot,unfortunately I can't accept your question right now !! I have to wait a while !!